# Will GetType() return the most derived type when called from the base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Will GetType() return the most derived type when called from the base class?

Example:

```
public abstract class A
{
    private Type GetInfo()
    {
         return System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(this.GetType());
    }
}

public class B : A
{
   //Fields here have some custom attributes added to them
}
```

Or should I just make an abstract method that the derived classes will have to implement like the following?

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected abstract Type GetSubType();

    private Type GetInfo()
    {
         return System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(GetSubType());
    }
}

public class B : A
{
   //Fields here have some custom attributes added to them

   protected Type GetSubType()
   {
       return GetType();
   }
}
```

Comment: well - did you try it out?

Comment: @BrokenGlass normally I would just do that but I am not at a computer ... just used my phone to make the post because a solution for a problem was starting to form and I was curious to know now! =P

Comment: Related: [“this” keyword type when called on an object of derived class from base class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29858243/3258851)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

`GetType()` will return the actual, instantiated type.  In your case, if you call `GetType()` on an instance of `B`, it will return `typeof(B)`, even if the variable in question is declared as a reference to an `A`.

There is no reason for your `GetSubType()` method.

Comment: Does it though? I am passing an instance of an object from its (abstract) super class, the receiver only sees the super class. 

Is it not that it will always return what the handle was defined as not the instance? - or am i missing something?

Comment: Ah ha.. the difference is using TypeOf(X) vs. x.GetType() i think

Answer (score 25):

`GetType` always returns the type that was actually instantiated. i.e. the most derived type. This means your `GetSubType` behaves just like `GetType` itself and thus is unnecessary.

To statically get the type information of some type you can use `typeof(MyClass)`.

Your code has a mistake though: `System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes` returns `Attribute[]` not `Type`.

Answer (score 12):

GetType always returns the actual type.

The reason for it is deep in the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) framework and [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime), as the JIT and CLR use the `.GetType` method to create a Type object in memory that holds the information on the object, and all access to the object and compilation are via this Type instance.

For more information, take a look in the book "CLR via C#" from Microsoft Press.

Answer (score 1):

Output:

> ```
> GetType:
>         Parent: 'Playground.ParentClass'
>         Child: 'Playground.ChildClass'
>         Child as Parent: 'Playground.ChildClass'
>
> GetParentType:
>         Parent: 'Playground.ParentClass'
>         Child: 'Playground.ParentClass'
>         Child as Parent: 'Playground.ParentClass'
> ```

Program.cs:

```
using Playground;

var parent = new ParentClass();
var child = new ChildClass();
var childAsParent = child as ParentClass;

Console.WriteLine("GetType:\n" +
                  $"\tParent: '{parent.GetType()}'\n" +
                  $"\tChild: '{child.GetType()}'\n" +
                  $"\tChild as Parent: '{childAsParent.GetType()}'\n");

Console.WriteLine("GetParentType:\n" +
                  $"\tParent: '{parent.GetParentType()}'\n" +
                  $"\tChild: '{child.GetParentType()}'\n" +
                  $"\tChild as Parent: '{childAsParent.GetParentType()}'\n");
```

ChildClass.cs

```
namespace Playground
{
    public class ChildClass : ParentClass
    {
    }
}
```

ParentClass.cs

```
namespace Playground
{
    public class ParentClass
    {
        public Type GetParentType()
        {
            return typeof(ParentClass);
        }
    }
}
```