# Why is the C# != operator comparing value types by reference?

Tags: c#, operators

I have the following code which is returning false:

```
 private static bool AreRowsEqual(string[] fieldNames, DataRow row1, DataRow row2)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= fieldNames.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (row1[fieldNames[i]] != row2[fieldNames[i]])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

This is surprising since there is only one field of type long being compared and the values of each field match as per immediate window output:

```
?row1[fieldNames[i]];
34
?row2[fieldNames[i]];
34

?row1[fieldNames[i]].GetType();
{Name = "Int64" FullName = "System.Int64"}
    [System.RuntimeType]: {Name = "Int64" FullName = "System.Int64"}

? row2[fieldNames[i]].GetType();
{Name = "Int64" FullName = "System.Int64"}
    [System.RuntimeType]: {Name = "Int64" FullName = "System.Int64"}
```

What have I overlooked here? I use != and == "everywhere" when comparing integers on value.

Comment: Can you post full content of both DataRows?
In your example 34 != 34 is false, so it couldn't return false, hence the problem will be with other values.

Comment: Well thats what I thought but apparently GetType()==Int64 is not "right" as per answers. Type is actually object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the [`DataRow.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx) indexer has a return type of `Object`, any value types would need to be [boxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before they are returned. Subsequently, your equality comparisons are performed on the object instances wrapping your values, not on the values themselves. To perform value comparison, you need to unbox your values by casting them back to their proper type, or use the polymorphic `Equals` method.

```
int i1 = 34;
int i2 = 34;
Console.WriteLine(i1 == i2);             // gives true

object o1 = i1;
object o2 = i2;
Console.WriteLine(o1 == o2);             // gives false
Console.WriteLine((int)o1 == (int)o2);   // gives true
Console.WriteLine(o1.Equals(o2));        // gives true
```

**Edit**: You need to draw a distinction between an object's runtime type and its declared type. When boxed, your items have a declared type of `object` (per the return type of the `DataRow.Item` indexer), but still have a runtime type of `long` (or `Int64`). Operators, such as `!=`, are resolved against the declared type, whilst instance methods that have been overridden in derived classes would be invoked against the runtime type. This is why `Equals` works correctly in the above case.

Comment: Why does GetType() not return object then?

Comment: @rism look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780584/will-gettype-return-most-derived-type-when-called-from-base-class) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

When you do:

```
(row1[fieldNames[i]] != row2[fieldNames[i]])
```

`row[x]` gives you an `object` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx

If you compare objects with `==` you compare the reference.

You have to cast to their primitive Datatype OR compare with `obj.Equals(obj2)`

For Example:

```
    object a = 2;
    object b = 2;

    if (a == b)
        Debug.WriteLine("== = true");
    if (a.Equals(b))
        Debug.WriteLine("equals = true");
```

Debug Output: 
equals = true