# Why GetType() returns derive class after explicitly casting derive class to base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

This is surely simple but is bugging me for a while so hope to get some detailed explanation here.  I know that when you do

```
BaseClass b = new DeriveClass();
```

`b`'s type is still `BaseClass` NOT `DeriveClass` because of implicit cast from the derive class to the base class. In fact, it's also legal to do

```
BassClass b = (BaseClass)new DeriveClass();
```

but compiler doesn't require to do this. Anyway, what I don't understand is after this cast when I try to call `b.GetType()` it returns `DriveClass` rather than `BaseClass`.
Why is this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780584/will-gettype-return-the-most-derived-type-when-called-from-the-base-class

Comment: Casting an object does not modify the object, it is still the same object. Casting just says that you want to reference the object in a certain way, and it verifies that the object can indeed be referenced in that way.

Comment: You should make sure that you understand the difference between an object reference and an object.

Comment: @usr: can you elaborate on the difference then?

Comment: @stt106 that's something well explained on the web. No need for me to elaborate. You'll not be successful using C# without understanding this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetType()` always returns the current type (checked at runtime, not compile time) of instance. It is written on the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets the Type of the current instance.

Code sample on msdn:

```
MyBaseClass myBase = new MyBaseClass();
MyDerivedClass myDerived = new MyDerivedClass();
object o = myDerived;
MyBaseClass b = myDerived;

Console.WriteLine("mybase: Type is {0}", myBase.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("myDerived: Type is {0}", myDerived.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("object o = myDerived: Type is {0}", o.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("MyBaseClass b = myDerived: Type is {0}", b.GetType());

// The example displays the following output:
//    mybase: Type is MyBaseClass
//    myDerived: Type is MyDerivedClass
//    object o = myDerived: Type is MyDerivedClass
//    MyBaseClass b = myDerived: Type is MyDerivedClass
```