# "this" keyword type when called on an object of derived class from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, method-hiding

If I have something like this:

```
class Base
{
    public void Write()
    {
     if (this is Derived)
      {
         this.Name();//calls Name Method of Base class i.e. prints Base
        ((Derived)this).Name();//calls Derived Method i.e prints Derived 
      }
     else
      {
        this.Name();
      }
    }

    public void Name()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public new void Name()
    {
        return "Derived";
    }
}
```

and use the following code to call it,

```
Derived v= new Derived();
v.Write(); // prints Base
```

then the `Name` method of base class gets called. but what would be the actual type of `this` keyword in the `Write` method? if that is of `Derived` type(as the Program control enters the first if block in `Write` method) then it is calling the base `Name` method, and why does the explicit casting,`(Derived)this`, change the call to the `Name` method of derived class?

Comment: What does this.GetType() say?

Comment: @EricJ. it should be this.GetType(), not typeof(this) since this is an instance not a type.

Comment: Good point, updated original comment

Comment: It is never a good idea to hide an existing method `Name()` by introducing a `new` method `Name()` with the same signature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` will always be of the derived class type.

The reason why in the call `this.Name();` calls the base class `Name()` method is because `Name` is not defined as a virtual method, thus it is being linked in compile time when the compiler knows nothing about the actual type of `this` that it will have at this point.

One more note regarding the code above. Generally in product code referring to a Derived class from the Base class explicitly is really a bad practice as it breaks one of the OOP principles that the Base class should not be aware about the classes which inherit it. However, assuming that the code above was just used for C++ investigation then this is of course ok.

Comment: then what about `((Derived)this).Name()`?

Comment: Also in this case there will be static binding to function `Name`, this time to the Derived class version. The difference, however, is that in this case you're explicitly instructing the compiler to treat `this` as an object of type Derived, thus the compiler translate the call to `Name()` to the address of the implementation in the derived class.

Comment: if I mark the `Name()` method as `virtiual`, the behavior would be the same?

Comment: It is helpful to separate the compile-time type from the actual type at run-time. `this` is of compile-time type `Base`. The overload resolution (binding) at compile-time reflects that. At run-time the type could be more specific (and is in this example), but the binding is already fixed. One can use `((dynamic)this).Name()` to have the binding happen based on the actual run-time type.

Comment: If you'll define `Name()` as `virtual` then the behavior will not be the same as in this case the Derived class version of `Name()` will be called rather than the Base version as in your original code.

Comment: this happens only if you override it in the base, right?

Comment: (Of course the declaration in `Derived` must use `override`, not `new`, if we want this virtual dispatch.)

Comment: And calling the inherited  `Write` method from Derived class has no effect on the `this` compile -time binding?

Comment: Since the only `Write` method defined is in the base class then the compiler will translate any call to this method from the derived class to the base class implementation.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielse. `this` is of compile-time type Base, So it is not always be of the derived class type?

Comment: @user3723486 The compile-time type is "always" `Base`, which means when you compile your program into bytecode the type the C# compiler uses for the `this` value is `Base`. The run-time type depends. If you said `(new Base()).Write()`, the run-time type would be `Base`. But since `v` is a `Derived` in your program, `v.Write()` leads to `this` being of run-time type `Derived`. Please understand that *compile-time* type ("declared" type) and *run-time* type ("actual" type) are two distinct notions.

Comment: Indeed it does, even for class indexers .. `this["key"]` ... will resolve to the derived type even if it is called in the base class.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using virtual and override if you want to access any overridden members in a derived class:

```
class Base
{
    public void Write()
    {
     if (this is Derived)
      {
         this.Name();//calls Name Method of Base class i.e. prints Base
        ((Derived)this).Name();//calls Derived Method i.e prints Derived 
      }
     else
      {
        this.Name();
      }
    }

    public virtual void Name()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Name()
    {
        return "Derived";
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use `Override` in the derived class - the fact that the method was defined as virtual in the base class means that the call will be done via the vtable that will redirect the call to the implementation of `Name()` in the derived class.

Comment: You must use `override`. Absence of `override` leads to a `new` method which has no relation to the `virtual` method inherited, and has no place in that "vtable".

Answer (score 1):

This is all your need. You do not need to and should not be checking the type from the base to handle logic. Any special logic should be be handled in the derived classes and probably want to mark methods up as `virtual` in the base and `override` in the derived classes.

```
class Base
{
    public void Write()
    {
        SomeWriteMethod(Name());
    }

    public virtual void Name()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Name()
    {
        return "Derived";
    }
}
```

If you want the actual name of the class in `Name()`, you just need to call `GetType().Name` in the base and it will automatically work for any derived classes as `GetType()` returns you the actual instanced type of the instance. Just like `GetType()` is of the actual instance, `this` is also your actual instance so any special logic will be of that class' implementation.

`this` is actually a redundant call in your base class. Either you specify it or you don't -- you get the same result. The reason you see mixed results is because you used the `new` operator. `new` only works when you are working with that explicit type. It basically hides other implementations in the chain. And so, `this` being in the context of `Base` is going to give your `Base.Name()` where as if you had overridden, `Derived.Name()` would have been used instead.

[MSDN: Knowing when to use override and new keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)

Here is an excellent answer about `new` -- [Why does calling a method in my derived class call the base class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717570/why-does-calling-a-method-in-my-derived-class-call-the-base-class-method)

Answer (score 0):

By casting `((Derived)this).Name()`, you are explicitly setting it to the derived class. Since you have `Write` defined in the base class, this will point method calls to it. This behavior occurs because you have not overridden the base method and you are calling it from the base class.