# Why does Person p = new Student() gives student type

Tags: c#, upcasting

Stupid question. So there is the code:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, I'm person!");
    }
}

class Student : Person 
{
    //
}
```

**Main**

```
Student student = new Student();
Person p = student;
Console.WriteLine(p.GetType()); // Student
```

Why does this return a `Student`? I thought that it should be `Person`, because we created `Person` instance and insert into it `Student` object

Comment: The underlying type is still `Student` though. You didn't create a `Person` instance at all, you just assigned the student into a variable of type `Person`

Comment: @DavidG thank you so much, sir, for your explanation

Comment: *`because we created Person instance...`*  No,  `new Student()` is the code to create the object..  `Person` is just the object variable to hold it.

Comment: Because `Student` is a type of `Person`, you may assign a `Person` variable to a `Student` object. This is one of the basic aspects of inheritance and polymorphic design in Object Oriented Programming (oop). I recommend reading up on basic polymorphism to get an understanding as to *why* it's implemented this way. Can you think of something you would do for any type of `Person`  and something that you would do for `Student` objects that might not apply to a different `Person` subtype (`Parent`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if type of `P` is Person, it is a referring to student . As you instantiated Student object, your P variable is just referring to the object of student.

[image: Student S is Referring to Person P]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @Sam, Does diagram helped you to understand what I mean to say or it is confusing you. If diagram does not help then I guess you can get better answers in the given [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5780584/6299857). I am happy to delete my answer, if it wont add much value to SO.